# Transform a python list to [[index] * value ] flattened

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list, and want to transform the list to `[[index] * value]` flattened.

For example if input is `[1, 2, 3, 1]`, output should be `[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]`. I can imagine to do the following.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 1]
result = []
for i,n in enumerate(A):
    result += [i] * n
```

The `result` is the output I want. But as you can see, the solution is not very elegant. How to do it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 1]

output = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) for _ in range(x)]
print(output) # [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some ways using `itertools` functions, though I think your loop is perfectly fine and j1-lee's is what I might've written if they hadn't already.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, count, starmap

result = [*chain(*map(repeat, count(), A))]
result = list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, count(), A)))
result = list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, enumerate(A))))
```